# production and local routing mismatching

Tags: reactjs, routes, next.js

I'm having hard time understanding why my local routing and production routing are mismatching.

I'm writing an app in next.js

In my _app.tsx file I have following lines

```
    if (!isUserLogged && Component.isRestricted) {
      redirect(res, '/login');

      return { pageProps: {} };
    }

    if (isUserLogged && !hasUserGivenConsent && !Component.tosPage) {
      redirect(res, '/accept-tos');

      return { pageProps: {} };
    }

    if (isUserLogged && hasUserGivenConsent && Component.tosPage) {
      redirect(res, '/');

      return { pageProps: {} };
    }

    if (isUserLogged && Component.isAuthPage) {
      redirect(res, '/');

      return { pageProps: {} };
    }
```

`Component.someProperty` are always statics in `pages/somePage.tsx` files.

isUserLoggedIn and hasUserGivenConsent are redux toolkit state.

My pages/login.tsx:

```
class LoginPage extends Component {
  static isRestricted = false;

  static isAuthPage = true;

  static getInitialProps = wrapper.getInitialPageProps(store => async ({
    res,
    query: {
      token,
      uid,
    },
  }) => {
    const { dispatch }: { dispatch: AppThunkDispatch } = store;

    if (
      !!token && typeof token === 'string' &&
      !!uid && typeof uid === 'string'
    ) {
      await dispatch(activateUser({
        token,
        uid,
      }))
        .unwrap()
        .catch(e => {
          redirect(res, '/expired-link ');
        });
    } else {
      dispatch(clearActivationStatus());
    }

    return {};
  });

  render() {
    return (
      <LoginForm />
    );
  }
}
```

Locally everything works as expected:

1. not logged user, trying to access restricted page -> `/login`
2. logged user, tos not accepted -> `/accept-tos`
3. logged user, tos accepted, trying to access tos page -> `/`
4. user clicking on activation mail is directed to `/login?uid=...&token=...` -> getInitialProps check if there are uid and token if so, then it posts a request to backend to activate account -> if ok user stays on login page -> if not redirects user to `/expired-link`

Production behavior:

1. (current problem) no matter if user is logged in or not it redirects to `/accept-tos` from any URL I type into browser.
2. (previous problem, not achievable due to current problem) If user clicked on the activation link `/login?uid=...&token=...` it redirected to `/` which is restricted path

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I ran a gitlab job that cleared the environment so thus it wasn't working.